# MakeCat failed in Windows 8

Tags: c++, signing, catalog

I´m having troubles creating a catalog with MakeCat in Windows 8.
After calling with verbose, MakeCat shows the next error:

> Failed: CryptCATCDFOpen.  Last Error: 0x00000003

If I do it with Windows 7 over the same file, I don't have troubles.

The Catalog Definition File has this content:

```
[CatalogHeader]
Name=Digi.dll.cat
ResultDir=C:\Users\JoséÁngel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project
[CatalogFiles]
<HASH>Digi.dll.manifest=Digi.dll.manifest
Digi.dll.manifest=Digi.dll.manifest
```

And the manifest of the dll has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Digi" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="82292917b7a6e156" type="win32" version="10.0.0.217"></assemblyIdentity>
  <dependency optional="yes">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Digi.Resources" version="10.0.0.217" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="82292917b7a6e156" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <file name="Digi.dll" hashalg="SHA1" hash="69447737c3bfaf30c611c1755bcfd0f31fbb4557">
    <asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity"></dsig:Transform>
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></dsig:DigestMethod>
      <dsig:DigestValue>GLP5Lao75uVf0ITDkD3b+yN/U8I=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </asmv2:hash>
  </file>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

The path of the result directory in the catalog definition file is too large.
Changing everything to a sorter path works correctly.